# Converting Double to Bool

Tags: c#, geometry

I am trying to find if given point is inside a circle and here is my solution for the moment

```
using System;

//Write an expression that checks if given point (x, y) is inside a circle K({0, 0}, 2).

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter x: ");
        double x = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter y: ");
        double y = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        bool insideCircle = (double)Math.Sqrt((x * x) + (y + y) <= 2);

    }
}
```

I am getting an error that i cannot convert from bool to double. Can someone help me?

Comment: `double insideCircle` instead of `bool insideCircle`. What do you think you cast your `Math.Sqrt` part to `double` and it should return `bool` instead? What do you want to get as a `bool` with your right side operation?

Comment: Use `Math.Sqrt((3 * 5) + (3 + 5)) <= 2;` (the right paranthesis is wrong)

Comment: I think you have that error in both directions. Write it out in smaller steps, as a learning exercise.

Comment: Why convert a `double` to a `bool`? Why not just use an `if` statement? (e.g. if (double in range) then bool = true)

Comment: enclose your `Math.Sqrt` part in `()` and then compare the result like `bool insideCircle = Math.Sqrt((x * x) + (y + y)) <= 2;`

Comment: You are trying to take the square root of a boolean expression.   Take the `<= 2` out of the call to `Sqrt`.

Comment: let's see the easy-points-seeker in action below ;-)

Comment: `bool insideCircle = Math.Sqrt((x * x) + (y + y)) <= 2;`

Comment: In addition to the answers provided, the `y + y` in your distance calculation should be `y * y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the `<= 2` outside the `Math.Sqrt()`.

```
        Console.Write("Enter x: ");
        double x = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter y: ");
        double y = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        bool insideCircle = Math.Sqrt((x * x) + (y + y)) <= 2;
```

Comment: Thank you that solved it! Sorry if it was stupid question.I am very new to programming.

Answer (score 2):

You've got your parentheses in the wrong place.

```
bool insideCircle = Math.Sqrt((x * x) + (y + y)) <= 2.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you meant:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter x: ");
        double x = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter y: ");
        double y = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        // <= 2 is outside the brackets, not inside
        bool insideCircle = Math.Sqrt((x * x) + (y + y)) <= 2;
    }
}
```